Can We Find a More Sparse $S$?
Original question
I am working with a sparse matrix $S$ with the assumption of sparsity such that in a matrix of $N^2$ elements, at most $2N$ are non-zero. (This sparsity condition could be adjusted if needed). I also assume $S$ is full rank. Let the singular value decomposition (SVD) of $S$ be given by
$$
S = U \Lambda V^T
$$
I am curious whether there exists a unitary matrix $V'$ such that $S' = U \Lambda V'^T$ results in a matrix $S'$ that is sparser than $S$. Here, "sparser" could mean having more zeros or a smaller L1 norm.
Alternatively, I am interested in understanding under what conditions such a matrix $V'$ does not exist. We could have more assumptions on $S$ to have some results.
Thanks to @Exodd, I've simplified my inquiry to whether there exists a unitary matrix $U'$ such that $S' = S U'$ results in a matrix $S'$ that is sparser than $S$. Here, "sparser" could mean having more zeros or a smaller L1 norm.
Actually, I am interested in understanding under what conditions such a matrix $U'$ does not exist. We could have more assumptions on $S$ to have some results. The assumption now I have is $diag(S)=1$
This question may seem open-ended or not strict, and I apologize if it appears foolish. I am looking forward to any insights or references that could guide me on this topic.

Update:
I have found some cases where a more sparse result can be achieved. However, my primary interest is in understanding under what conditions a more sparse result cannot be achieved.
For example, consider $S = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $S' = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Performing SVD on $S$ and $S'$, we find that both have the same $U$ and $\Lambda$, but different $V$ matrices. In particular:
$$
S' = 1 \cdot [1 \ 0 \ 0]^T [0 \ 1 \ 0]
$$
$$
S = 1 \cdot [1 \ 0 \ 0]^T \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right]
$$

using a QR decomposition you can always bring any dense matrix in an upper rectangular one through multiplication by orthogonal matrices

ps. changing $V$ does not change the product $SS^T$ and its sparsity should give you insight on the optimal sparsity

@Exodd Thanks for your insightful response. But a upper rectangular matrix can be not sparser than S. Have assumptions on $SS^T$ might be a good idea.
